# SQLCMD using batch variable in query

Tags: sql-server, batch-file, sqlcmd

If I'm using `sqlcmd` in a batch script, can I reference a batch variable inside the query?

So that if I do something like

```
for /f "delims= " %%a in ('sqlcmd -S SERVER -d DATABASE -Q 
    "SELECT Column1 FROM Table1 WHERE Column1=[specific number]"') do set var1=%%a
```

how could I do something like this?:

```
for /f "delims= " %%b in ('sqlcmd -S SERVER -d DATABASE -Q
    "SELECT Column2 FROM Table1 WHERE Column2=[var1]"' do set var2=%%b
```

So that the `WHERE` condition in the second `sqlcmd` statement is using the variable set in the first statement?

Answer (score 0):

Change Column2=[var1] to Column2=%var1%

Comment: Okay so I can still use the same syntax indiscriminately?

Comment: The %var1%  will be replaced by real value during batch execution.

Comment: This batch has some issues you need to be aware. 
1). Select may return multiple records. Last value will be assigned to the variable. SELECT TOP 1 may help. 
2). Use SET NOCOUNT ON; before the statement, othervise line "(1 rows affected)" will be the last line. 
3). If SELECT affect 0 records  then last line will be "-----------" an that will be assigned to the variable.

Comment: Ah, so it won't return null if there are no results?

Comment: No. SQLCMD will not return NULL. It returns message "(0 row(s) affected)"

Answer (score 0):

You can pass arguments from the environment to sqlcmd by using the -v switch and referencing the parameters in your sql statement by the $(variable) syntax. E.g. in your second statement :

```
for /f "delims= " %%b in ('sqlcmd -S SERVER -d DATABASE -Q
    "SELECT Column2 FROM Table1 WHERE Column2=$(var1)" -v var1=%var1%' do set var2=%%b
```

Comment: Are the parenthesis around var1 i.e. `(var1)` part of syntax or just implying a placeholder?

Comment: They are indeed, the syntax is $(externalVariableName)